# How to debug a '4005 Path Not Found' error?

Tags: pusher

I am trying to integrate Pusher with my web application that uses backbone.js. I'm following the Pusher with Backbone guide in the Pusher docs.

So I'm seeing this error pop up in the web console on application start up

```
Pusher : Error : {"type":"PusherError","data":{"code":4005,"message":"Path not found"}}
```

What is this 'path' that cannot be found? I found nothing in the Pusher docs.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

A 4005 error generally means that the WebSocket URL you are using doesn't identify an application to connect to.

In terms of usage of the Pusher JavaScript library this means you've likely supplied an empty string as the `app_key` to the `Pusher` constructor.

```
var pusher = new Pusher('');
```

You can see this in action here:
http://jsbin.com/evulaj/1/edit

Open the JavaScript console to see the error. You can also check the `app_key` value set by checking `pusher.key`.

*Note: I appreciate this error is a bit cryptic. I'll see if we can remedy this*

Answer (score 1):

in my case, `wsHost: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_WS_HOST` was giving an empty value, and fixed it by changing `.env` file.

```
PUSHER_WS_HOST=my.host.com
MIX_PUSHER_WS_HOST="${PUSHER_WS_HOST}"
```

or you can do:

```js
wsHost: window.location.hostname
```