# Laravel 5 Pusher Server Could not Find App By Key

Tags: laravel-5, pusher

I am having a problem that when I add task it will not triggered the event.
how to I solve this ?
And besides how to I solve the websocket error?
I am using Pusher in order to create a realtime event..
[caption of the error message of the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NzTr7.png)

Answer (score 1):

The image shows you are using a Pusher Application Key with the value `YOUR_APP_KEY`. This needs to be changed to be the application key you get for your app when you sign in via https://dashboard.pusher.com

If you are using Event Broadcasting in Laravel the configuration for your server will be in `config/broadcasting.php` as per http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/events#broadcast-configuration

If you are using the [Pusher Laravel Bridge](https://github.com/vinkla/pusher) then configuration will be in `config/pusher.php`.

In both cases you will need to pass the Pusher Application Key configuration through to your blade in order to use the value. Or - for testing purposes - you could hard code the key.

If you get a 4005 error message from Pusher then your environment variable is not being passed properly as this means the application cannot be found. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/13802175/39904

Comment: I have a question about this error `Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at ws://ws.pusherapp.com/app/YOUR_PUSHER_KEY?protocol=7&client=js&version=2.2.4&flash=false` how do chage the `ws://ws.pusherapp.com` to a localhost ?

Comment: Pusher is a hosted service so in order to use it within a Laravel app you need to sign up for a free account (you can't use `localhost`). Upon doing so you will get credentials that will allow you to change the `YOUR_PUSHER_KEY` value to a real application key value. In your JavaScript look for `new Pusher('YOUR_PUSHER_KEY');`